# Transferring Data From Activity To BroadCast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I am making an Alarm app and when user enter the Title and Description it shows a notification on selected time.
I want to store two string values named as `txttitle` and `txtdesc` in `intents` and send them in `broadcast-receiver` when a notification arrives, the title and description of that notification should be the title and description string values respectively. I've successfully issued the notification but there is no title and description that i need, it is something like `app.support.v7.widget` 
**Here is my code.**  
***AddNote.java***

```
public class AddNote extends AppCompatActivity {

    int mHour, mMin, hour , min, mYear, mMonth, mDay;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note);
        final CheckBox chckRem = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cHcRem);
        final Button btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTok);

        chckRem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (chckRem.isChecked()){
                    /** It is checked*/
                    // Get Current Date
                  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddNote.this,
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                               final int day = dayOfMonth;
                               final int yer = year;
                                final int month = monthOfYear;

                                    /** LAUNCH THE TIMEPICKER*/
                                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                                    mMin =c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                                    /** LAUNCH THE TIMEPICKER*/
                                    // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                                    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(AddNote.this,
                                            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                                                      int minute) {
                                                    /**tHIS*/
                                                    hour = hourOfDay;
                                                    min = minute;
                                                    int sec = 0;
                                                    Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
                                                    cl.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                                                    cl.clear();
                                                    cl.set(yer, month, day, hour, min);
                                                    EditText txtitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tTit);
                                                    EditText txtdesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tDet);
                                                    Intent notMessage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificatioRec.class);
                                                    notMessage.putExtra("TITLE", txtitle.toString().trim());
                                                    notMessage.putExtra("DEC", txtdesc.toString().trim());
                                                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddNote.this, 0, notMessage, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                                    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cl.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
                                                    Toast.makeText(AddNote.this, "Reminder Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            }, mHour, mMin, false);
                                    timePickerDialog.show();

                                }
                            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    datePickerDialog.show();

                }

            }
        });

        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    TextoDatabaseHelper textoDatabaseHelper = new TextoDatabaseHelper(AddNote.this);
                    SQLiteDatabase db = textoDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                    Calendar calend = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int YEAR = calend.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int MONTH = calend.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int DAY = calend.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    String date = DAY + "-" + MONTH + "-" + YEAR;
                    EditText txt_title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tTit);
                    String Title = txt_title.getText().toString().trim();
                    EditText txt_Desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tDet);
                    String Desc = txt_Desc.getText().toString().trim();
                    insertNote(db, Title, Desc, date);
                    Toast.makeText(AddNote.this, "Note Added" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    AddNote.this.finish();
                }catch (SQLException e){
                    Toast.makeText(AddNote.this, "Can't add a new note! Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public static void insertNote(SQLiteDatabase db, String title, String desc, String date){
        ContentValues Notes = new ContentValues();
        Notes.put("TITLE", title);
        Notes.put("DESCRIPTION", desc);
        Notes.put("DATE", date);
        db.insert("NOTES", null, Notes);
    }
}
```

***NotificatioRec.java***

```
public class NotificatioRec extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("TITLE");
        String desc  = intent.getStringExtra("DESC");
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 , new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle(title).setContentText(desc);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_ALARM);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

However, the only problem is that it doesn't show the title and description.

Comment: Try to change string `notMessage.putExtra("TITLE", txtitle.toString().trim());` to `notMessage.putExtra("TITLE", String.valueOf(txtitle.getText()).trim());` and for "DEC" too.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this below
**For broadcast to send to activity**

```
 Intent smsIntent = new Intent("otp");
            smsIntent.putExtra("message",sms_str);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(smsIntent);
```

**For Activity to receive that intent above.**

```
 private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("otp")) {



            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your Adnote activity from where you want to send intent from

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.action.data");
intent.putExtra("otp", otp);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Get Data On Receive Method

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   String action = intent.getAction();
   Log.i("onReceive Method", "" + action);

   if(action.equals("my.action.data")){
          String otp= intent.getExtras().getString("otp");

   }
 }
```

Add below code in your receiver(Manifest File)

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true">
     <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
     <action android:name="my.action.data" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```